# Bluetooth drivers for Win2008 serv 64

Tags: 64-bit, bluetooth, windows-server-2008

I'm trying to use my noname bluetooth dongle with  Win2008 server 64x and there is no luck. The problem is in the drivers: in 32x version I use Toshiba BlueTooth Stack and there is nothing fo 64x. Any options for 64x?

Answer (score 0):

You might try to use Windows Vista drivers (if they support your device).

You will need working Windows Vista installation to steal drivers from (check [instructions](http://blog.jmedved.com/2009/02/bluetooth-on-windows-server-2008.html)).

Comment: I have drivers for Vista, but only for 32x. Can't install them to Server2088 64x. Are you talking about to use stok Vista bluetooth drivers on Server (no metter 32 or 64-bit)?

Comment: I am talking about stock drivers, but you must have 64-bit version of Vista somewhere. Drivers from 32-bit version will not do. :(